# Gradle: Couldn't connect to Kotlin daemon on Windows

Tags: windows, gradle, kotlin, compilation, daemon

When I try a task that involves a `compileKotlin` (or `compileTestKotlin`), then I receive this warning and the result is *unpleasant long duration of the build process*:

> Could not perform incremental compilation: Could not connect to Kotlin compile daemon
>
> Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.

---

I'm not sure the issue is related to my OS (Windows) or not, but I have the same project (with synchronized files) on a remote machine with Linux OS and the issue doesn't exist there. See below comparison:

1. The project on my remote machine (**Linux**) with a little change in Kotlin sources (in one module):

   ```
   $ ./gradlew build

   Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
   Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
   See https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

   BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
   46 actionable tasks: 17 executed, 29 up-to-date
   ```
2. Same project on my local machine (**Windows**) with same change:

   ```
   > gradlew build                                                                                       

   > Task :backend:compileKotlin                                                                         
   Could not perform incremental compilation: Could not connect to Kotlin compile daemon                 
   Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.                                          

   warning: the '-d' option with a directory destination is ignored because '-Xbuild-file' is specified  

   Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.           
   Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.                                 
   See https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings       

   BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 14s                                                                               
   46 actionable tasks: 17 executed, 29 up-to-date
   ```

Especially see build duration time in above two samples (and *the warning after `compileKotlin` task on Windows machine*). Even though my local machine (Windows) has more powerful hardware, but the result is the opposite (Gradle daemon is running on both).

---

In order to further analyzability I also publish the output of `gradle -v`  and `java -version` on both machines:

1. **Linux**:

   ```
   $ ./gradlew -v

   ------------------------------------------------------------
   Gradle 5.0
   ------------------------------------------------------------

   Build time:   2018-11-26 11:48:43 UTC
   Revision:     7fc6e5abf2fc5fe0824aec8a0f5462664dbcd987

   Kotlin DSL:   1.0.4
   Kotlin:       1.3.10
   Groovy:       2.5.4
   Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
   JVM:          11.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.1+13)
   OS:           Linux 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 amd64


   $ java -version
   openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
   ```
2. **Windows**:

   ```
   > gradlew -v                                                           

   ------------------------------------------------------------           
   Gradle 5.0                                                             
   ------------------------------------------------------------           

   Build time:   2018-11-26 11:48:43 UTC                                  
   Revision:     7fc6e5abf2fc5fe0824aec8a0f5462664dbcd987                 

   Kotlin DSL:   1.0.4                                                    
   Kotlin:       1.3.10                                                   
   Groovy:       2.5.4                                                    
   Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018   
   JVM:          11.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.1+13)                    
   OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64


   > java -version                                                     
   openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16                          
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)           
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
   ```

---

Global `gradle.properties` files on two machines are exactly same (and there is no poject-local `gradle.properties` file for none):

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

(without comments)

---

UPDATE 1:

There is no problem when Gradle JVM has been set to `JDK 8`. But with `JDK 9+` you can see the issue.

---

UPDATE 2:

I updated my Kotlin plugin from `1.3.10` to `1.3.11`. Also, tested `1.3.20-eap-52`. But the issue persists.

---

UPDATE 3:

I ran Gradle's `compileKotlin` task with `--debug` option to get more information. The most important parts of the output are:

*<sup>Note: Below tasks have been run when Gradle daemon was running, Kotlin compile daemon was stopped (if already running) and a little change has been made in a Kotlin source.</sup>*

**I.** When using **JDK 8** as Gradle's JVM (*OK*):

```
11:01:44 PM: Executing task 'compileKotlin --debug'...
...
22:58:20.512 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] [KOTLIN] Kotlin compiler args: -Xadd-compiler-builtins -Xbuild-file=C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Temp\kjps3085207010700515672GradleKotlinJVM.script.xml -classpath D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8\1.3.10\71d0fa967493eb76648b575edf1762cb2d0c7f10\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.3.10\4d147bf43060dc43d61b096e24da1e67dfe0c032\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.10\b178c1501609c6e4ee8be635513cb023a466457d\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.10\1b19d99229dcedad7caf50534dce38fe82845269\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar -d D:\Devel\IdeaProjects\GradleKotlinJVM\build\classes\kotlin\main -jvm-target 1.8 -Xload-builtins-from-dependencies -module-name GradleKotlinJVM -no-reflect -no-stdlib -Xplugin=D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable\1.3.10\e96a6125793c4ab0258119fcdce9d182f42d32b0\kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.3.10.jar -verbose
...
22:58:33.515 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: found daemon on port 17519 (270393 ms old), trying to connect
22:58:33.515 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: cannot connect to registry: Connection refused: connect
22:58:33.515 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: found fresh run file 'C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\kotlin\daemon\kotlin-daemon.2019-01-06T19-23-50.118Z.ef9f56f7564e12d191d0ba8e50b581f8.17519.run' (270393 ms old), but no daemon, ignoring it
22:58:33.515 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: found daemon on port 17502 (63606 ms old), trying to connect
22:58:33.515 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: cannot connect to registry: Connection refused: connect
22:58:33.515 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: found fresh run file 'C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\kotlin\daemon\kotlin-daemon.2019-01-06T19-27-16.900Z.ef9f56f7564e12d191d0ba8e50b581f8.17502.run' (63606 ms old), but no daemon, ignoring it
22:58:33.515 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: starting the daemon as: C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk1.8.0_202\jre\bin\java -cp D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-compiler-embeddable\1.3.10\adc9e577de39fba3db6d60662892118afedd713\kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.3.10\dd02865be0351707554b16a896b766b2396cdafa\kotlin-reflect-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.10\b178c1501609c6e4ee8be635513cb023a466457d\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-script-runtime\1.3.10\1d2bac36f99b84e1493244f12629bc0756a3ff90\kotlin-script-runtime-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.10\1b19d99229dcedad7caf50534dce38fe82845269\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk1.8.0_202\lib\tools.jar -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dkotlin.environment.keepalive org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.KotlinCompileDaemon --daemon-runFilesPath C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\kotlin\daemon --daemon-autoshutdownIdleSeconds=7200 --daemon-compilerClasspath D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-compiler-embeddable\1.3.10\adc9e577de39fba3db6d60662892118afedd713\kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.3.10\dd02865be0351707554b16a896b766b2396cdafa\kotlin-reflect-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.10\b178c1501609c6e4ee8be635513cb023a466457d\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-script-runtime\1.3.10\1d2bac36f99b84e1493244f12629bc0756a3ff90\kotlin-script-runtime-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.10\1b19d99229dcedad7caf50534dce38fe82845269\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk1.8.0_202\lib\tools.jar
22:58:33.515 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: Received the message signalling that the daemon is ready
22:58:33.516 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: new daemon started, trying to find it
22:58:33.516 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: found daemon on port 17519 (277256 ms old), trying to connect
22:58:33.516 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: cannot connect to registry: Connection refused: connect
22:58:33.516 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: found fresh run file 'C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\kotlin\daemon\kotlin-daemon.2019-01-06T19-23-50.118Z.ef9f56f7564e12d191d0ba8e50b581f8.17519.run' (277256 ms old), but no daemon, ignoring it
22:58:33.516 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: found daemon on port 17502 (70469 ms old), trying to connect
22:58:33.516 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: cannot connect to registry: Connection refused: connect
22:58:33.516 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: found fresh run file 'C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\kotlin\daemon\kotlin-daemon.2019-01-06T19-27-16.900Z.ef9f56f7564e12d191d0ba8e50b581f8.17502.run' (70469 ms old), but no daemon, ignoring it
22:58:33.516 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: found daemon on port 17507 (70 ms old), trying to connect
22:58:33.516 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: connected to the daemon
22:58:33.518 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Options for KOTLIN DAEMON: IncrementalCompilationOptions(super=CompilationOptions(compilerMode=INCREMENTAL_COMPILER, targetPlatform=JVM, reportCategories=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], reportSeverity=3, requestedCompilationResults=[0]), areFileChangesKnown=true, modifiedFiles=[D:\Devel\IdeaProjects\GradleKotlinJVM\src\main\kotlin\Main.kt], deletedFiles=[], workingDir=D:\Devel\IdeaProjects\GradleKotlinJVM\build\kotlin\compileKotlin, customCacheVersionFileName='gradle-format-version.txt', customCacheVersion=4, multiModuleICSettings=MultiModuleICSettings(buildHistoryFile=D:\Devel\IdeaProjects\GradleKotlinJVM\build\kotlin\compileKotlin\build-history.bin, useModuleDetection=false), usePreciseJavaTracking=truelocalStateDirs=[D:\Devel\IdeaProjects\GradleKotlinJVM\build\classes\kotlin\main])
22:58:33.524 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] Daemon worker: reuse connection
...
22:58:35.428 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] [KOTLIN] [IC] compiling with args: [-Xadd-compiler-builtins, -Xbuild-file=C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Temp\kjps6683894818132820708GradleKotlinJVM.script.xml, -classpath, D:\Devel\IdeaProjects\GradleKotlinJVM\build\classes\kotlin\main;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8\1.3.10\71d0fa967493eb76648b575edf1762cb2d0c7f10\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.3.10\4d147bf43060dc43d61b096e24da1e67dfe0c032\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.10\b178c1501609c6e4ee8be635513cb023a466457d\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.10\1b19d99229dcedad7caf50534dce38fe82845269\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar, -jvm-target, 1.8, -Xload-builtins-from-dependencies, -module-name, GradleKotlinJVM, -no-reflect, -no-stdlib, -Xplugin=D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable\1.3.10\e96a6125793c4ab0258119fcdce9d182f42d32b0\kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.3.10.jar, -Xreport-output-files, -verbose]
...
11:01:53 PM: Task execution finished 'compileKotlin --debug'.
```

**II.** When using **JDK 11** as Gradle's JVM (***Problem here***):

```
11:01:44 PM: Executing task 'compileKotlin --debug'...
...
23:01:45.888 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] [KOTLIN] Kotlin compiler args: -Xadd-compiler-builtins -Xbuild-file=C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Temp\kjps11452575260818015211GradleKotlinJVM.script.xml -classpath D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8\1.3.10\71d0fa967493eb76648b575edf1762cb2d0c7f10\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.3.10\4d147bf43060dc43d61b096e24da1e67dfe0c032\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.10\b178c1501609c6e4ee8be635513cb023a466457d\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.10\1b19d99229dcedad7caf50534dce38fe82845269\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar -d D:\Devel\IdeaProjects\GradleKotlinJVM\build\classes\kotlin\main -jvm-target 1.8 -Xload-builtins-from-dependencies -module-name GradleKotlinJVM -no-reflect -no-stdlib -Xplugin=D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable\1.3.10\e96a6125793c4ab0258119fcdce9d182f42d32b0\kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.3.10.jar -verbose
...
23:01:48.134 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: starting the daemon as: C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk-11.0.1\bin\java -cp D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-compiler-embeddable\1.3.10\adc9e577de39fba3db6d60662892118afedd713\kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.3.10\dd02865be0351707554b16a896b766b2396cdafa\kotlin-reflect-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.10\b178c1501609c6e4ee8be635513cb023a466457d\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-script-runtime\1.3.10\1d2bac36f99b84e1493244f12629bc0756a3ff90\kotlin-script-runtime-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.10\1b19d99229dcedad7caf50534dce38fe82845269\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dkotlin.environment.keepalive org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.KotlinCompileDaemon --daemon-runFilesPath C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\kotlin\daemon --daemon-autoshutdownIdleSeconds=7200 --daemon-compilerClasspath D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-compiler-embeddable\1.3.10\adc9e577de39fba3db6d60662892118afedd713\kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.3.10\dd02865be0351707554b16a896b766b2396cdafa\kotlin-reflect-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.10\b178c1501609c6e4ee8be635513cb023a466457d\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-script-runtime\1.3.10\1d2bac36f99b84e1493244f12629bc0756a3ff90\kotlin-script-runtime-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.10\1b19d99229dcedad7caf50534dce38fe82845269\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar
23:01:48.134 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: [daemon] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
23:01:48.134 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: Received the message signalling that the daemon is ready
23:01:48.134 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: new daemon started, trying to find it
23:01:48.134 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: starting the daemon as: C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk-11.0.1\bin\java -cp D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-compiler-embeddable\1.3.10\adc9e577de39fba3db6d60662892118afedd713\kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.3.10\dd02865be0351707554b16a896b766b2396cdafa\kotlin-reflect-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.10\b178c1501609c6e4ee8be635513cb023a466457d\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-script-runtime\1.3.10\1d2bac36f99b84e1493244f12629bc0756a3ff90\kotlin-script-runtime-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.10\1b19d99229dcedad7caf50534dce38fe82845269\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dkotlin.environment.keepalive org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.KotlinCompileDaemon --daemon-runFilesPath C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\kotlin\daemon --daemon-autoshutdownIdleSeconds=7200 --daemon-compilerClasspath D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-compiler-embeddable\1.3.10\adc9e577de39fba3db6d60662892118afedd713\kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.3.10\dd02865be0351707554b16a896b766b2396cdafa\kotlin-reflect-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.10\b178c1501609c6e4ee8be635513cb023a466457d\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-script-runtime\1.3.10\1d2bac36f99b84e1493244f12629bc0756a3ff90\kotlin-script-runtime-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.10\1b19d99229dcedad7caf50534dce38fe82845269\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar
23:01:48.134 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: [daemon] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
23:01:48.134 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: Received the message signalling that the daemon is ready
23:01:48.134 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: new daemon started, trying to find it
23:01:48.137 [WARN] [org.gradle.api.Project] Could not perform incremental compilation: Could not connect to Kotlin compile daemon
23:01:48.137 [WARN] [org.gradle.api.Project] Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.
23:01:49.486 [LIFECYCLE] [system.err] 
23:01:49.486 [ERROR] [system.err] logging: using Kotlin home directory <no_path>
23:01:49.521 [ERROR] [system.err] logging: configuring the compilation environment
23:01:50.538 [ERROR] [system.err] logging: loading modules: [java.se, jdk.accessibility, jdk.attach, jdk.compiler, jdk.dynalink, jdk.httpserver, jdk.jartool, jdk.javadoc, jdk.jconsole, jdk.jdi, jdk.jfr, jdk.jshell, jdk.jsobject, jdk.management, jdk.management.jfr, jdk.net, jdk.scripting.nashorn, jdk.sctp, jdk.security.auth, jdk.security.jgss, jdk.unsupported, jdk.unsupported.desktop, jdk.xml.dom, java.base, java.compiler, java.datatransfer, java.desktop, java.xml, java.instrument, java.logging, java.management, java.management.rmi, java.rmi, java.naming, java.net.http, java.prefs, java.scripting, java.security.jgss, java.security.sasl, java.sql, java.transaction.xa, java.sql.rowset, java.xml.crypto, jdk.internal.jvmstat, jdk.management.agent, jdk.jdwp.agent, jdk.internal.ed, jdk.internal.le, jdk.internal.opt]
23:01:53.459 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: the '-d' option with a directory destination is ignored because '-Xbuild-file' is specified
...
11:01:53 PM: Task execution finished 'compileKotlin --debug'.
```

**III.** When using **JDK 11** as Gradle's JVM, but on **Linux** (*OK*):

```
$ ./gradlew compileKotlin --debug
...
01:33:20.145 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: starting the daemon as: /usr/local/jdk-11.0.1/bin/java -cp /usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.3.10/adc9e577de39fba3db6d60662892118afedd713/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.10.jar:/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.3.10/dd02865be0351707554b16a896b766b2396cdafa/kotlin-reflect-1.3.10.jar:/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.10/b178c1501609c6e4ee8be635513cb023a466457d/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar:/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-script-runtime/1.3.10/1d2bac36f99b84e1493244f12629bc0756a3ff90/kotlin-script-runtime-1.3.10.jar:/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.10/1b19d99229dcedad7caf50534dce38fe82845269/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar:/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dkotlin.environment.keepalive org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.KotlinCompileDaemon --daemon-runFilesPath /usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.kotlin/daemon --daemon-autoshutdownIdleSeconds=7200 --daemon-compilerClasspath /usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.3.10/adc9e577de39fba3db6d60662892118afedd713/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.10.jar:/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.3.10/dd02865be0351707554b16a896b766b2396cdafa/kotlin-reflect-1.3.10.jar:/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.10/b178c1501609c6e4ee8be635513cb023a466457d/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar:/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-script-runtime/1.3.10/1d2bac36f99b84e1493244f12629bc0756a3ff90/kotlin-script-runtime-1.3.10.jar:/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.10/1b19d99229dcedad7caf50534dce38fe82845269/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar:/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar
01:33:20.145 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: [daemon] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
01:33:20.145 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: Received the message signalling that the daemon is ready
01:33:20.145 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: new daemon started, trying to find it
01:33:20.145 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: found daemon on port 17613 (56 ms old), trying to connect
01:33:20.145 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] i: connected to the daemon
01:33:20.145 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Options for KOTLIN DAEMON: IncrementalCompilationOptions(super=CompilationOptions(compilerMode=INCREMENTAL_COMPILER, targetPlatform=JVM, reportCategories=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], reportSeverity=3, requestedCompilationResults=[0]), areFileChangesKnown=false, modifiedFiles=null, deletedFiles=null, workingDir=/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/test/build/kotlin/compileKotlin, customCacheVersionFileName='gradle-format-version.txt', customCacheVersion=4, multiModuleICSettings=MultiModuleICSettings(buildHistoryFile=/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/test/build/kotlin/compileKotlin/build-history.bin, useModuleDetection=false), usePreciseJavaTracking=truelocalStateDirs=[/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/test/build/classes/kotlin/main])
...
01:33:21.920 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] [KOTLIN] [IC] compiling with args: [-Xadd-compiler-builtins, -Xbuild-file=/tmp/kjps15100965302804914597GradleKotlinJVM.script.xml, -classpath, /usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.10/71d0fa967493eb76648b575edf1762cb2d0c7f10/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.10.jar:/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.3.10/4d147bf43060dc43d61b096e24da1e67dfe0c032/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.10.jar:/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.10/b178c1501609c6e4ee8be635513cb023a466457d/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar:/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.10/1b19d99229dcedad7caf50534dce38fe82845269/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar:/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar, -jvm-target, 1.8, -Xload-builtins-from-dependencies, -module-name, GradleKotlinJVM, -no-reflect, -no-stdlib, -Xplugin=/usr/share/nginx/html/0xy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable/1.3.10/e96a6125793c4ab0258119fcdce9d182f42d32b0/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.3.10.jar, -Xreport-output-files, -verbose]
...
```

There are some suspected events in the above logs (second), but I can't exactly understand the meaning of them and that they are related to my problem or not:

1. Why two (exactly equal) tries has occurred to start *Kotlin compile daemon*?
2. There are some errors. But they are all after warnings about Kotlin's daemon problem.
3. The latest error/warning:

   ```
   [ERROR] [system.err] warning: the '-d' option with a directory destination is ignored because '-Xbuild-file' is specified
   ```

   is the most suspected thing! Because it's the only message you can't find in other logs. Also see [here](https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt/issues/1230). I asked about it in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54067016/gradle-compilekotlin-task-warning-the-d-option-with-a-directory-destinatio).

Comment: I just had to restart to fix the error!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Finally, I found the root cause of the issue ... After some days!

I found out the issue is from my user account. So decided to revert any user-dependent thing to its first state. During clearing `Temp` folder (in `AppData\local\`) accidentally I saw these files:

```
kotlin-daemon.Û²Û°Û±Û¹-Û°Û±-Û°Û¸.Û°Û³-ÛµÛ´-Û±Û²-Û¶Û´Û¸.00.log
kotlin-daemon.Û²Û°Û±Û¹-Û°Û±-Û°Û¸.Û°Û³-ÛµÛ´-Û±Û²-Û¶Û´Û¸.00.log
```

Yes! The problem has come from ***unicode encoding issues*** (probably between `NTFS` and `UTF-8`)! Although these are `log` files and maybe not important their names, this issue can exist somewhere else!

As you can guess, damaged part of file names are **`date` & `time`**. So (unfortunately) I forced to revert my personalizations of *Windows user account's date & time formats* from my favorite (`Persian (Iran)`) to `English (United States)`:

[image]

*And the problem solved immediately:*

```
> wmic process where "name='java.exe'" get processId, executablePath, commandLine /format:list

CommandLine=D:\Devel\JDK\openjdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx1536m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp D:\Devel\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.0-all\4mxuau4c77thx8zlvtz4xiez7\gradle-5.0\lib\gradle-launcher-5.0.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 5.0
ExecutablePath=D:\Devel\JDK\openjdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe
ProcessId=9168

CommandLine=D:\Devel\JDK\openjdk-11.0.1\bin\java -cp D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-compiler-embeddable\1.3.10\adc9e577de39fba3db6d60662892118afedd713\kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.3.10\dd02865be0351707554b16a896b766b2396cdafa\kotlin-reflect-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.10\b178c1501609c6e4ee8be635513cb023a466457d\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-script-runtime\1.3.10\1d2bac36f99b84e1493244f12629bc0756a3ff90\kotlin-script-runtime-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.10\1b19d99229dcedad7caf50534dce38fe82845269\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dkotlin.environment.keepalive org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.KotlinCompileDaemon --daemon-runFilesPath C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\kotlin\daemon --daemon-autoshutdownIdleSeconds=7200 --daemon-compilerClasspath D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-compiler-embeddable\1.3.10\adc9e577de39fba3db6d60662892118afedd713\kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.3.10\dd02865be0351707554b16a896b766b2396cdafa\kotlin-reflect-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.10\b178c1501609c6e4ee8be635513cb023a466457d\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-script-runtime\1.3.10\1d2bac36f99b84e1493244f12629bc0756a3ff90\kotlin-script-runtime-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.10\1b19d99229dcedad7caf50534dce38fe82845269\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar;D:\Devel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar
ExecutablePath=D:\Devel\JDK\openjdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe
ProcessId=12088
```

The second process is ***Kotlin compile daemon***.

---

Also `log` files:

```
kotlin-daemon.2019-01-08.03-51-11-111.00.log
kotlin-daemon.2019-01-08.03-51-11-111.00.log.lck
```

<sup>*(Note that `.log.lck` file didn't exist in previous state!)*</sup>

Comment: It worked! I hope they change it in later releases.

Comment: Yes! The Russian format caused the same error.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I've fixed by clearing some cache in Users folders, in particular:

```
C:\Users\user\.android\build-cache\
C:\Users\user\.android\cache\
C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\
```

Not sure which one made a difference but after clearing all this, the error went away.

Comment: didn't help. prolly unrelated.

Comment: cleared first and second, it helped, thx

Answer (score 7):

I know this question has an answer but when I did the same the project still throw the same error at my face which is:

> Could not connect to kotlin daemon

But then I solved it by going to Android studio's terminal and I ran this code `.\gradlew --stop` after that I cleaned the project and ran it again which solved my problem and I was able to download the app.
I hope someone reads it and it fixes his issue.

Comment: said Stopping Daemon(s) and stopped 1. and then rebuilt, voila. thnx

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded kotlin from ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'to ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50', and it's fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Restarting ADB did the work for me. Just run this on the terminal:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```